# Aggregating results of a stored procedure within a select statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate

I have a few tables that I'm joining to pull out information about notifications and put it into a queue table for my app to pull from.

My code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO DW_Applications.Notify.Queue
    (
        UserID,
        NotificationMessage
    )
    SELECT 
        rcp.UserID,  
        IIF(r.AggregateIfMultiple = 1, REPLACE(n.AggregateMessageTemplate, '<number>',  getAggregateNumber(n.daxSproc)), n.MessageTemplate) AS Template
    FROM DW_Applications.Notify.Notifications AS n
    JOIN DW_Applications.Notify.Rules AS r ON r.NotificationID = n.ID
    JOIN DW_Applications.Notify.Recipients AS rcp ON rcp.RuleID = r.ID
    WHERE rcp.IsActive = 1 AND rcp.UserID = @UPN
```

My problem is the second line here in the SELECT statement. My non-existant getAggregateNumber user-defined function is meant to call a given stored procedure (I have one sproc that goes with each kind of notification), and return the aggregate of it's results (an int).  If I could have my way, I would write my user-defined function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAggregateNumber (@daxSproc varchar(200), @Startdate varchar(100))
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultTable TABLE (entityID VARCHAR(200), amount INT);
    INSERT INTO @resultTable
    (
        entityID,
        amount
    )
    EXEC @daxSproc @Startdate = @StartDate;
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM @resultTable)
END;
```

The problem is you can't use an insert exec statement in a function.

So what's the best way to do this? Make another sproc that does what my function is supposed to do? I wish I could aggregate the results of a stored procedure all within my original select statement that inserts into my queue.

If it helps to visualize, my Notifications table looks like the below with each row having a different sproc that I need to call and aggregate (see last column here):

[image]

Comment: Why not `INSERT` the results of the procedure into a (temporary) table and then use that in your query, rather than trying to `INSERT` the data into a table variable inside a function (which you're not allowed to do).

Comment: Because I have a separate stored procedure that I have to aggregate results from per notification (per row in the table), so I don't want to make a separate temp table and separate sproc call for each row

Comment: Then you'll need to put your logic into the query. You're trying to treat a procedure like it's a table; it's not.

Comment: It looks like you're passing the pre-determined name of a procedure as a parameter to your as-yet-to-be-written function and only now discovered that's not going to work for you? You'd perhaps be better off putting the logic of whatever this (or these) procedures do in a table-valued function.

Comment: Just edited the question so you can visualize the Notifications table. I have different logic per notification and I need to make this dynamic. The results of each stored procedure for each notification do return a table

Comment: There may be a clever workaround but it would appear this design is going to force you down the RBAR road.

Comment: table-valued functions is a good idea. The problem is that within each of those sprocs in the notifications table, I also I have to call another sproc, which I don't think I can do in a table-valued function. It's complex architecture. Lots of sprocs on top of sprocs

Comment: Perhaps you could change the design of these procs to take a table-valued parameter and you could pass each set of relevant rows to each once and then process the results collectively.

Comment: It does sounds like the design is the problem. (Inline) Table Value Functions on top of iTVFs may well not be particularly performant either; it depends how far down the rabbit hole goes. But you can't execute a procedure for each row, not without some *very* slow RBAR methods or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor *all* of your sprocs into inline TVFs, then you can simply `CROSS APPLY` them. Can't say without seeing all relevant code